# Can't find the request for http://localhost:8082/{params}'s Observer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, cxf

I have a very simple Java REST service code concept here.

The problem is that when I am hitting the URL the below message is showing up in the console:
**Can't find the request for http://localhost:8082/REST/services/patientservices/getallpatients's Observer**

I am using **cxf.jaxrs.component-scan=true** for spring to read the annotations.

Below are the classes and configuration file:

**pom.xml:**

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
       https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <parent>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
       <version>2.3.11.RELEASE</version>
       <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
<groupId>com.mayukh.rs</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxrs</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>jaxrs</name>
<description>JAX RS</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**PatientService.java:**

```
package com.mayukh.rs;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

import com.mayukh.rs.model.Patient;

@Path("/patientservices")
public interface PatientService {

@Path("/getallpatients")
@GET
List<Patient> getPatients();
}
```

**PatientServiceImpl.java:**

```
package com.mayukh.rs;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.mayukh.rs.model.Patient;

@Service
public class PatientServiceImpl implements PatientService {
    
    Map<Long, Patient> patients = new HashMap<>();
    long currId = 123;
    
    public PatientServiceImpl() {
        
        init();
    }
    
    public void init() {
        Patient patient = new Patient();
        patient.setId(currId);
        patient.setName("Mayukh");
        patients.put(patient.getId(), patient);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Patient> getPatients() {
 
        Collection<Patient> results = patients.values();
        List<Patient> response = new ArrayList<>(results);
        
        return response;
    }

}
```

**application.properties:**

```
server.port=8082
cxf.jaxrs.component-scan=true
server.servlet.context-path=/REST
```

Comment: did you follow a tutorial / tool when you created that service?

Comment: Yeah I'm following a Udemy course

Comment: Your request is `/REST/services/patientservices/getallpatients` but your context is only `/REST`, so where is that `/services` subpath coming from / where is it mapped?

Comment: By default cxf exposes all the endpoints in /services relative URL

Comment: I am using cxf.jaxrs.component-scan=true for spring to read the annotations. what do you mean by that? I don't really understand why you need to use cxf

Comment: Because I am not creating any bean yet or mentioning any custom dispatcher-servlet. Using cxf is just another way to do all that in a concise manner and for simple applications like this.

Comment: Also Spring should be reading the cxf.jaxrs.component-scan=true to create the necessary endpoints on the fly and save time from writing any separate Configuration files.

Comment: ... Spring can do all that jus tfine without cxf. Have you tried following the spring-boot tutorials? this 'll create you a functioning rest-service in springboot in about 5 minutes: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Comment: If you follow the following link you will find that Apache CXF is the most commonly used, most stable and is currently the industry standard. That's why I am preferring CXF over Spring Webservices. 
https://dzone.com/articles/apache-cxf-vs-apache-axis-vs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a mistake in the **pom.xml** file.

Instead of **jaxws** dependency it should be **jaxrs** dependency.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
```